# How to get ratio of width x height of an image on disk / file?

Tags: c#, .net, image, jpeg

I have my userpictures saved as file on my HDD.
(Not in database).

I will get the height and width of this *.jpg-files, how to do that?

(Background: I must calculate the ratio between hight and width to bring it to a specified height and width without stretching it).

Comment: Are you trying to read the header directly? Or are you ok with loading the image into memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many formats support a header with that info but others don't [so...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx)

```
 Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
 int height = img.Height;
 int width = img.Width;
```

Answer (score 6):

I think it is also worth mentioning that System.Drawing.Image implements IDisposable, so you should always use a using statement or call the Dispose() method on your object to make sure that you are releasing any unmanaged system resources.  Example:

```
using (Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path))
{
    int height = img.Height;
    int width = img.Width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the FromFile static method on the System.Drawing.Bitmap class to load your images. The returned Bitmap instance has Width and Height properties. Altnatively, you can also construct a new Bitmap passing a string path to your image file as a constructor parameter.